# Batch file loop IP systeminfo

Tags: loops, batch-file, ip

I'm trying to figure out how to get a batch file to loop through a list of ips on a text to then export the results of a `systeminfo` file into another file.

So, for example - my `rackipsonly.txt` file has the following data:

```
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
etc...
```

I want to have a batch that reads the IP of each line and returns the hostname and it's uptime and return it to an output file `UP_Log.txt`.

Here is what I have gotten thus far and can't get it to where I need it to work

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ("C:\rackiponly.txt") do (
    echo.   
    echo %%A >> "C:\UP_LOG.txt"
    systeminfo /s:%%A | findstr /C:"Host Name:" >> "C:\UP_LOG.txt"
    systeminfo /s:%%A | findstr /C:"System Boot Time" >> "C:\UP_LOG.txt"
)
```

Comment: Read the information output when entering `For /?` at the Command Prompt. The part specific to the `/F` option should show you the differences between, a command and a set of one or more files/strings. You should really try to find a more efficient way of retrieving the host name and boot time; running one of the most time consuming utilities once is bad enough, running it twice unnecessarily is worse.

Comment: Something similar to this may be more suitable for your task. `@WMIC /Node:@C:\rackiponly.txt /Output:"C:\UP_LOG.csv" OS Get LastBootUpTime /Format:CSV`.

Answer (score 0):

As Compo suggested:

- run systeminfo only once
- use the default regex mode of findstr and a regular expression anchored at line begin (replace spaces in search strings with a dot; a space combines search strings in an **OR** condition)

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\01\SO_52594783.cmd
@echo off
Set "IPs=C:\rackiponly.txt"
(Echo:[%date% %time:~0,8%] Started processing %IPs% 
    for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%IPs%") do (
        echo.   
        echo.%%A
        systeminfo /s:%%A | findstr /I "^Host.Name ^System.Boot.Time"
    )
) >> "C:\UP_LOG.txt"
```